# How to understand security policy error message

Tags: windows, windows-10, email, office365

I'm trying to add a work account to Windows 10 mail and calendar, but it looks like my security settings are not compatible. I'm presented with an error, but I'm not sure how to read it. Does it tell me what settings I need to change?

I searched for the error code, but it looks like the solutions are aimed at administrators instead of users.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/2464593

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error code in this instance isn't that important.  What is important is that it's telling you, that you don't comply with the policies set before you can connect to the service.

That list you posted are requirements you need to meet.  It's probably one of the first 5 that are causing you an issue. My guess would be it's the password complexity requirement

Also if you have a Microsoft account connected in Windows 10 (@live, @outlook, etc), you may need to remove that, as not all settings are compatible with those accounts.